Mock C# callback method in pester
New to Pester. Using 5.5 in VSC . I am trying to write a test for a Get-Flags
I have a Perform.ps1 one that looks something like this :
param(
    [System.Action[SSK.Actions.WhenSucceeded]]$MyCallback
)
...
function Get-Flags 
param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [string]
        $flags
)
{
 ... Code i Want to Test....
}

SSK.Action.WhenSucceeded is a callback method in a C# class.
Then i write a test in Pester that looks like this:
BeforeAll {
    . "$PSScriptRoot/Perfom.ps1"

    
}


Describe 'Get-Flags' {
    It 'Should not any flags when parameter is not provided' {
        
        $sameFlags = Get-Flags
    $sameFlags.Count | Should -Be 0
    }
}

When calling Get-Flags in Pester to test I get an error
RuntimeException: Unable to find type [SSK.Actions.WhenSucceeded]
I tried to do
Mock -ModuleName "SSK.Actions" -CommandName WhenSucceeded { }
then i get an error No modules named 'SSK.Actions' are currently loaded.

"SSK.Action.WhenSucceeded is a callback method in a C# class." - WhenSucceeded is necessarily a type, not a method. What exactly are you planning on passing as the argument to $myCallback?

planning to pass a string to it. It something like $myCallback.Invoke($flags)


I tried to do Mock -ModuleName "SSK.Actions" -CommandName WhenSucceeded { }

PowerShell's module namespacing doesn't map onto that of .NET - they're two separate systems, one built on top of eachother.
The easiest way to mock a .NET type is to compile a dummy type with Add-Type:
BeforeAll {
  if ($null -eq ('SSK.Actions.WhenSucceeded' -as [type])) {
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition 'using System; namespace SSK.Actions { public class WhenSuceeded { public DateTime When = DateTime.Now; } }'
  }
}

Note that the lifecycle of .NET types is tied to the underlying runtime, not the hosting PowerShell runspace - the generated type will persist even after Pester returns
